# Mysterious hidden TCP connection from page with AJAX

Tags: ajax, http, tcp

I am observing this weird situation. I have a page from which I want to do some AJAX requests to local server for testing. I noticed that there is huge lag for TTFB on first request, around 10-15 seconds. The server does almost nothing, Curl gets response within 100ms. After little digging I got a feeling that browser initiates some "hidden" connections. To prove this I ran Wireshark and turned out my hypothesis was right. But it only get's weirder.

Browser initiates bare TCP connections to server, doesn't send anything and closes them after 10 seconds. Those connections are not seen in debug tools in Network tab. The weirdest part is that those connections are initiated before I trigger AJAX request, actually the connection is initiated even if I don't do anything on the page, without any AJAX at all. I seem to be able to reproduce for any server, here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ywg2ov6/12/) with example. At the moment I open or refresh this page my browser shoots TCP connections to server:

[image]

Here is page from jsfiddle,

```
<button id='l'>list</button>

$('#l').click(function () {
    $.get(
        'http://63.245.215.53/test/'
    )
    .done(function (data) {});
});
```

My machine, Mac OS 10.10.3, Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)

So question:

Why does browser initiate such connections? They don't seem to be reused, when I actually initiate AJAX request browser opens new TCP connection.
How does browser knows what address IP address to connect to? Apparently browser remembers for some reason which servers did I request from a page.

Comment: Did you check other browsers/machines? Maybe try with private browsing tab? I'd guess bad addons/proxy settings or antivirus if curl is fine.

Comment: @atamanroman I was able to reproduce on another Mac+Chrome. It doesn't reproduce in incognito mode even after I enabled all extensions in incognito, so it is not extensions.

Comment: @atamanroman no proxy and no antivirus

Comment: That's a single tcp connection, isn't it (seq increases)? Since the packets seem empty, I'd bet its some network magic (e.g. MTU discovery).

Comment: Those are two connections, they have different ports, but what is more important that they are opened without me doing any AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Chrome initiates so called speculative or predictive connections based on previous experience. There is good explanation [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116982#c5).

Summary:

> The second way that speculative connections emerge is based on
>   "previous experience" visiting a site.  For example, if you vistit
>   www.cnn.com, you'll (today) see that you'll need to get about 48
>   resources (and/or connections) to i.cdn.turner.com.  This list uses a
>   smoothing heuristic, to attempt to remember how many other connections
>   were needed in the past.  Chromium can then make up to 6 connections
>   speculatively to the subresource site (e.g., i.cdn.turner.com) when a
>   connection is made to the containing resource (e.g., www.cnn.com).

So Chrome remembers about AJAX request from the page and predicts that page might send request once again. Interesting that if I stop local server and AJAX request results in error, next time Chrome will not open predictive connection. If I bring server up again Chrome will start opening predictive connections only after I refresh page couple of times, apparently this is done to prevent waste with unreliable resources.

One way to stop Chrome from creating such connections is run it with this command line key:

```
--disable-preconnect
```